# Duplicate AUTO_INCREMENT Id upon insertion into another column?

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id

Say I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE bananas (
    id    INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name  CHAR(127),
    order INT
);
```

And I want the initial order field of the rows to match insertion sequence so, order == id

Now I can make the insert with some dummy value, check what ID it got and then update the row but this seems dumb. 
How do I make this happen upon insert?

```
INSERT INTO bananas (name, order) VALUES ($name, ???);
```

Comment: If `order` always has the same value as `id`, why do you need it?

Comment: @Nick It has the same initial value but it might change later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediatly after running an `INSERT`, you can use [function `LAST_INSERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to recover the id of the last successfully inserted record and run an `UPDATE` query :

```
INSERT INTO bananas (name, ord) values ('foo', 100);
UPDATE bananas SET ord = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

[This DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jgdfb9sMCUM8JpJU5MnTdq/0) demonstrates how this works.

PS : column name `order` clashes with the corresponding SQL keyword, I renamed that column `ord` in the code.